# Intellisense not complaining about incorrectly implemented (access modifiers) abstract methods in child class

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I have an abstract class and a child class that implements some of the methods within it, my problem is with my intellisense (VSCode), the abstract methods are defined as protected, but it is not complaining if the method is implemented as protected (but complains if I define it as private)

```
abstract class TestParent {
  protected abstract SomeFunction();
}

class ChildClass extends TestParent {
  public SomeFunction() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

^ No error

I would expect to get an error saying that ChildClass incorrectly extends TestParent and that SomeFunction should be protected.

```
class ChildClass extends TestParent {
   SomeFunction() {
     console.log("hello");
   }
}
```

^ No error

```
class ChildClass extends TestParent {
   private SomeFunction() {
     console.log("hello");
   }
}
```

^ Thats the only case that gives me the incorrect extending error.

I found this by accident, what I would expect is that, when I try to implement the method, to get a squiggly telling me that I should mark it as protected, because any other case is incorrect implementation (access modifier (other than protected) or no access modifier)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is intentional.
You can't give stricter access modifier than parents in the derived class; Liskov substitution principle is applied here if I understand correctly.
FYI: Same in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKgU0gBWCmwDtEBvAKAQQAcoB7CbebAEwVEhngQGV6AttgBiAV2LwAlvWIAKAJQAuBADd6k1gG4KAXwoUUaDAGEAFpOStjqdAmwAPJsVYYc%20QiXJVaUSSuBMfIIi4lIyCgiU1NSwMmD0yNgAdMj0AOayAESm2MipmfLa1Ho6QA).

Comment: I understand that, my point is that I don't even get a warning to notify me, something like "heyy, you can keep this public, but, double check because it is defined as protected in the parent, are you sure its not supposed to be protected instead of public?" Something like that